# Custom global tags in ASP.NET/IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, content-management-system

I would like to make some custom tags, that can be used all-round in HTML on an IIS. I would like to implement these special tags using C#/ASP.NET.

What I want to achieve, is that I have a central database, where I store certain information, like service prices, and information like that. Then I would like to be able to use special tags in HTML, that are being parsed, and transformed on server side, before displaying the data on the client side.

I have a few different services running on the IIS, and our main content comes from a closed source CMD, so I am not able to implement anything central in the CMS, therefor I would like this to be like a layer after the content from the CMS is generated.

What I have access to in the closed source CMS, is to change values in web.config and Global.asax.

Please come up with suggestions on how I can implement such a service. I am open for all solutions.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to create your own HTML tag that gets parsed and expanded server side into some meaningful data? Do you have access tot he .aspx page containing the markup you wish to modify? Your intent isn't incredibly clear here.

Comment: To me it sounds like you need to use `*.ascx` controls.

Comment: I will look into the suggestions mentioned below, of making a HTTP filter, that can inject the needed functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at HTTP filters as this would allow you to inject functionality such as you describe into the response pipeline of even a fixed CMS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301704.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649096.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will also look into this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement this with a `HttpModule` and a [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx) :

- Create a `HttpModule` to select the content to which you'd like to apply a `Filter`
- Use the `Filter` to replace your custom tags with your own content

[Rick Strahl wrote an article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/13/Capturing-and-Transforming-ASPNET-Output-with-ResponseFilter) about using `Response.Filter` to compress the output of any page, and there are [other examples](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx) which should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're after is an ASP.NET User Control. The syntax for your markup might be something like:

```
<cms:MyTag runat="server" MyProperty="myvalue" />
```

The control could then access your CMS and generate HTML and/or JavaScript that the browser needs to render the page.

You can also create templated controls that can contain other controls.